# Localize DataAnnotations in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

In my asp.net core (.net5) application I have a form with a required field. When the field is empty I have

[image]

"The XX field is required"... In English... I want to translate it in French. I mean, I don't really want to *translate*, I want *to use the French version* of the message. I don't want to add Resource files, because I have any custom strings to translate, I just want to use existing messages, but in French.

I started to read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but did't really get the point if the article really proposes me to translate each message manually by myself.

I added this one in the Configure

```
var supportedCultures = new[] { "fr-FR" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

however this didn't change the message...

nor setting the culture params via URL, like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one french version, you just need to define the error message in [Required]

attribute, like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ Nom est obligatoire")]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
}
```

And if your shared code refers to the documention you shared, you need to add Resource file to

define the translated message, or the message will not changed.

**Edit:**

If you have other properties, you can define a customRequired attribute:

```
 public class CustomRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public CustomRequiredAttribute()
    {         
    }
    
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Le champ {validationContext.DisplayName} est obligatoire";
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{   
    [CustomRequired]  //custom attribute
    public string Nom { get; set; }        
    [CustomRequired]
    public string PreNom { get; set; }
}
```

To use your custom attribute, you should add **ModelState.IsValid** in your post action, so if invalid, it will return the input view to show the errorMessages,like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Privacy(MyModel myModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Index");
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I have *any* message in `Required` attribute. It uses by default, the default message. So, I want to use the **default** message, but just the **French** one. Should I now copy-paste the same message on every `Nom`, and then on every `Prenom` and on every other property I created?

Comment: @Serge You can use a custom attribute, and write required logic to get property name and design error messages in it, check my edited answer.

Comment: is there a way do not hardcode the french translation? I mean that is example for IsRequired, but there are so many another DataAnnoattions!

Comment: the English messages, are not hardcoded, why the French ones should be hardcoded? I mean is not *custom*, or specific translation I need. I need the *default*, but not English one. I am not translator, I mean, I am developer )

Comment: linked to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33073